# Avg. product list position of added to cart product

Tags: google-analytics, google-bigquery

I'd like to return the Avg. product list position of added to cart product. I'm using the googlemerchandisestore.com. The idea is to calculate the avg. product position of the `Search Results` product list for each product that has been added to cart during sessions.

So far I have the following query:

```
SELECT
  visitId,
  prods.productSKU AS SKU,
  prods.v2ProductName AS Name,
  prods.productListName AS ProductList,
  AVG(prods.productListPosition) AS Average_Position
FROM
  `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`,
  UNNEST(hits) hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product) prods
WHERE
  (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170601'
    AND '20170731') and prods.productListName = "Search Results"
GROUP BY
  visitId,
  SKU,
  Name,
  ProductList
ORDER BY
  Average_Position ASC
```

This query return me the avg. product position of the `Search Results` product list for ALL the product. So I need to find a way to filters out product that as not been added to cart.

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't test but maybe this helps you:

```
SELECT
  sku,
  name,
  (SELECT AVG(position) FROM UNNEST(positions) AS position) AS avg_position
FROM(
  SELECT
    ARRAY(SELECT AS STRUCT
      productSKU AS sku,
      v2ProductName AS name,
      ARRAY_AGG(IF(productListName='Search Results', productListPosition, NULL) IGNORE NULLS) AS positions,
      MAX(IF(ecommerceAction.action_type='3', TRUE, NULL)) AS is_carted
    FROM UNNEST(hits) LEFT JOIN UNNEST(product)
    GROUP BY sku, name) AS hits
  FROM
    `bigquery-public-data.google_analytics_sample.ga_sessions_*`
  WHERE
    (_TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN '20170601' AND '20170631')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits), UNNEST(product) WHERE productListName = 'Search Results')
    AND EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM UNNEST(hits) WHERE ecommerceaction.action_type = '3')
), UNNEST(hits)
WHERE is_carted
  AND ARRAY_LENGTH(positions) > 0
```